# Check if a string contains only number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check if a `string` contains only valid number in the following format

```
123.456
123
.356
```

But it should reject anything that contains non-numbers including double dots. Here are some invalid formats

```
d123.456
123d
12d3
d.1256
12d.456
12.d12
12.d45d
12.45.56
```

I have done the following

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '123.00' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END
```

When seems to work except for the case where there is more than one dot in the string.

How can I tweak the regular expression to only allow one dot otherwise return 'Invalid'?

Comment: Those are not regular expressions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest `try_convert()`:

```
select (case when try_convert(col, float) is not null then 'valid' else 'invalid' end)
```

The one possible downside is exponential format; `1e6` is a valid number for instance.

An alternative is the `where` approach; you just need more complete logic:

```
select (case when col like '%[^0-9.]%' then 'invalid'
             when col like '%.%.%' then 'invalid'
             else 'valid'
        end)
```

Comment: Thank you That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 5):

There's a sql server built in function:

```
Select CASE WHEN isnumeric([fieldname]) THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid" END
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC check the datatype not the value so any string will return false

Comment: select isnumeric('123.00') returns true

Comment: @MikeA that is absolutely false. IsNumeric does NOT check the datatype. What would be the point of that? How about this? select ISNUMERIC('1')

Comment: IsNumeric is not the answer here. It returns far too many false positives in this case.

Comment: Here is the definition from Docs "ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0. Valid numeric data types include the following:" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: @MikeA when the input expression evaluates to a numeric data type. That means it can be converted to a numeric datatype. It has nothing to do with the datatype being input.

Comment: Check out this article about ISNUMERIC. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC%28%29/71512/

Comment: Just wanted to add here, but ISNUMERIC() also accepts decimal characters etc, which in itself is not an number. This causes problems sometimes when someone just wants the field to house numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not tied to regular expressions, SQL Server has an [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function you can use for this.

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: ISNUMERIC check the datatype not the value so any string will return false

Comment: Their example seems to dispute that: `SELECT name, **isnumeric(name) AS IsNameANumber**, database_id, isnumeric(database_id) AS IsIdANumber   
FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a horribly named function. It should be something more like ValueIsSomethingThatCanBeConvertedToAnyDatatypeThatIsRoughlyANUmber. For example 1e3 will return true.

Comment: @MikeA that is absolutely false. IsNumeric does NOT check the datatype. What would be the point of that? How about this? select ISNUMERIC('1')

Comment: I agree it evaluate the expression but it also accepts +-, currency  symbol, and e for power.

Answer (score 3):

`TRY_PARSE` will let you compare the input value to any/all numeric datatypes you decide to allow -- for example:

```
SELECT 
   TRY_PARSE('123.456' as int) as [int],
   TRY_PARSE('123.0' as float) as [float],
   TRY_PARSE('d123.456' as int) as [int],
   TRY_PARSE('d123.456' as float) as [float]
```

FWIW -- `ISNUMERIC` is often suggested, and is certainly the best-*sounding* function name :-) -- but doesn't work the way most folks seem to expect.  (It allows math and currency symbols, etc.)

Comment: This is what I get 
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 14
'TRY_PARSE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 + (sorry I didn't clarify that)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution for **NOT LIKE** clause is:

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```